# Webpack plugin parser not finding local or module function calls

Tags: javascript, parsing, webpack, webpack-plugin

I'm writing a code analytics webpack plugin that wants to find all instances of a  function name in a webpack bundle.

I made a repo for this question: https://github.com/RonPenton/webpack-parser-fail-demo

So the parser is really simple, just looks like this:

```
    class ParsePlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.plugin('compilation', function (compilation, data) {

            data.normalModuleFactory.plugin('parser', function (parser, options) {

                parser.plugin(`call $findme`, function (expr) {
                    console.log("found $findme!");
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

https://github.com/RonPenton/webpack-parser-fail-demo/blob/master/parse.js

All I want to do is find all instances of $findme() in code and record information about them. At a later time, I may even end up altering the calls, but that's for another day.

When I supply this source file, all is well: https://github.com/RonPenton/webpack-parser-fail-demo/blob/master/good.js

```
$findme("Testing");
$findme("Testing too...");
```

When I run webpack, the output shows both instances were found:

```
found $findme!
found $findme!
Hash: a6555af5036af17d9320
Version: webpack 3.6.0
Time: 69ms
  Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
good.js  2.52 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./good.js 47 bytes {0} [built]
```

But when I use a different entry point, where the function is defined either locally (https://github.com/RonPenton/webpack-parser-fail-demo/blob/master/bad.js) or in an external module (https://github.com/RonPenton/webpack-parser-fail-demo/blob/master/bad2.js), suddenly the parser stops finding these methods.

```
function $findme(input) {
    console.log(input);
}
$findme("Testing");
$findme("Testing too...");
```

====

```
import { $findme } from './findme';
$findme("Testing");
$findme("Testing too...");
```

So what's the deal? I tried digging into the webpack source code, and as far as I can tell, this seems intentional. But there's literally no documentation about why it's done this way, and not a comment in sight.

Is this not something that can be done with plugins?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The webpack parser weirdly only calls those hooks when your functions are called or retrieved a certain way. That's why your hook worked when the function was invoked one way, but didn't work when it was imported from somewhere.

I was trying to find all calls to an object method and had the same issue.

This github issue made by another person goes into more detail: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9480

To resolve this you need to trick the webpack Parser into thinking that function/method calls that it doesn't want to call hooks on for some reason are Identifiers, something like what's done here: https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/blob/9f6f7983312c66f857e79b744e4ec257cc287b8b/dist/InlineViewDependenciesPlugin.js

Here are the relevant bits from webpack's code:
[image]
[image]

You need to use the parser 'evaluate' hook to return a custom `BasicEvaluatedExpression` instance that has `isIdentifier` set to true for all function calls that you want to find. Then the `call` hook will get called with the full expression. In my case I need the full CallExpression that contains both the function and its arguments.